# Entity Framework COUNT is doing a SELECT of all records

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Profiling my code because it is taking a long time to execute, it is generating a SELECT instead of a COUNT and as there are 20,000 records it is very very slow.

This is the code:

```
var catViewModel= new CatViewModel();

var catContext = new CatEntities();

var catAccount = catContext.Account.Single(c => c.AccountId == accountId);

catViewModel.NumberOfCats = catAccount.Cats.Count();
```

It is straightforward stuff, but the code that the profiler is showing is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].xxxxx AS yyyyy, 
[Extent1].xxxxx AS yyyyy, 
[Extent1].xxxxx AS yyyyy, 
[Extent1].xxxxx AS yyyyy // You get the idea
FROM [dbo].[Cats] AS [Extent1]
WHERE Cats.[AccountId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=7
```

I've never seen this behaviour before, any ideas?

Edit: It is fixed if I simply do this instead:

`catViewModel.NumberOfRecords = catContext.Cats.Where(c => c.AccountId == accountId).Count();`

I'd still like to know why the former didn't work though.

Comment: That looks like the call for `Single` to me.

Comment: Call to Single generates: `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (2) 
XXX as YYY, (etc.)
FROM [dbo].[Account] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[AccountId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=7`

Comment: `Single` pulls back a record immediately.

Comment: How is `catAccount.Cats` declared ?

Comment: Standard pointing at the DB and pressing 'go' for generating the model. From Daniel's comment above though I'm guessing the immediacy of Single is the cause of the problem, seems that EF might give up being clever after that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have 2 completely separate queries going on here and I think I can explain why you get different results. Let's look at the first one

```
// pull a single account record
var catAccount = catContext.Account.Single(c => c.AccountId == accountId);
// count all the associated Cat records against said account
catViewModel.NumberOfCats = catAccount.Cats.Count();
```

Going on the assumption that `Cats` has a `0..*` relationship with `Account` and assuming you are leveraging the frameworks ability to lazily load foreign tables then your first call to `catAccounts.Cats` is going to result in a `SELECT` for all the associated `Cat` records for that particular account. This results in the table being brought into memory therefore the call to `Count()` would result in an internal check of the `Count` property of the in-memory collection (hence no `COUNT` SQL generated).

The second query

```
catViewModel.NumberOfRecords = 
    catContext.Cats.Where(c => c.AccountId == accountId).Count();
```

Is directly against the `Cats` table (which would be `IQueryable<T>`) therefore the only operations performed against the table are `Where`/`Count`, and both of these will be evaluated on the DB-side before execution so it's obviously a lot more efficient than the first.

However, if you need both `Account` and `Cats` then I would recommend you eager load the data on the fetch, that way you take the hit upfront once

```
var catAccount = catContext.Account.Include(a => a.Cats).Single(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Most times, when somebody accesses a sub-collection of an entity, it is because there are a limited number of records, and it is acceptable to *populate the collection*. Thus, when you access:

```
catAccount.Cats
```

(regardless of what you do next), it is **filling that collection**. Your `.Count()` is then operating on the local in-memory collection. The problem is that you don't want that. Now you have two options:

- check whether your provider offer some mechanism to make that a query rather than a collection
- build the query dynamically
- access the core data-model instead

I'm pretty confident that if you did:

```
catViewModel.NumberOfRecords =
    catContext.Cats.Count(c => c.AccountId == accountId);
```

it will work just fine. Less convenient? Sure. But "works" is better than "convenient".